# Freeing malloc of unknown size

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to free the malloc that is generated with a not fixed number of arrays.

```
char ** get_moves(){
    // some code
    char **moves = malloc(sizeof(char *) * k); // 'k', could ranges between 1~9
        if (!moves){
            return NULL;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            moves[i] = malloc(82);
            if (!moves[i]) {
                free (moves);
                return NULL;
            }
    // more code

    return moves;
}

int main(){

    //some code
    char **res = get_moves(some_input);
    //more code
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(res)/sizeof(res[0)); i ++){
        free(res[i]);
    }
    free(res);

}
```

In one of the inputs to get_move, res should have 2 arrays but the sizeof(res)/sizeof(res[0) gives me just 1.

How is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: I'd probably keep track of the size someplace but I'm no expert.

Comment: You have potential memory leaks in the `get_moves` function. What if the allocation of `moves[i]` fails after a few allocations has been made? You don't free the previously allocated pointers.

Comment: And to concur with @RickyMutschlechner, you need some way of keeping track of the size. And the `sizeof` trick only works on proper arrays, not on pointers (because `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size *of the pointer*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to keep track of the element count of the array, if you don't want to pass it to every function when passing the array, you can combine both pieces of information in a struct, like here

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ArrayOfStrings
{
    int    count;
    char **data;
};

struct ArrayOfStrings get_moves()
{
    struct ArrayOfStrings result;
    char **moves;

    // some code

    result.count = 0;
    result.data  = malloc(sizeof(char *) * k); // 'k', could ranges between 1~9
    if (result.data == NULL)
        return result;
    result.count = k;

    moves = result.data;    
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        moves[i] = malloc(82);
        if (moves[i] == NULL) 
        {
            /* also free succesfully allocated ones */
            for (int j = i - 1 ; j >= 0 ; --j)
                free(moves[j]);
            free(moves);
        }
        result.count = 0;
        result.data  = NULL;
        return result;
    }
    // more code

    return result;
}

int main(){

    //some code
    struct ArrayOfStrings res = get_moves(some_input);
    //more code
    for (int i = 0; i < res.count ; i ++)
        free(res.data[i]);
    free(res.data);
    return 0; // you should return from main.
}
```

`sizeof` is not for the length of an object's content but for the size of a data type, it is computed at compile time.

So in your case

```
sizeof(res) / sizeof(res[0]) == sizeof(char **) / sizeof(char *) == 1
```

since `sizeof(char **) == sizeof(char *)` it's just the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 sizeof(res)
```

Returns the `sizeof(double-pointer);`

So if you intend to get the number of pointers stored then you might not get this by doing what you are doing.

You need to do something like

```
for(i=0;i<k;i++) /* As I see you are allocating k no of pointer Keep track of it*/
    free(res[i]);

free(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`res` is in fact not an *array of arrays of `char` type*. Instead it is a *pointer to pointer to `char` type*. `sizeof(res)` will give you the size of `char**`. You need to keep track of the number of allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the maximum number of arrays to allocate is small (9), you can simplify your code by allocating the maximum number. Fill the unused elements with NULL:

```
#define MAX_K 9
char **moves = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_K); 

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    ...
}
for(int i = k; i < MAX_K; i++){
    moves[i] = NULL;
}
```

To deallocate, just ignore the NULL pointers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_K; i ++){
    if (res[i])
        free(res[i]);
}
free(res);
```

Comment: I'm getting leaks: `574 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1`